# How to add angular2 component to an angularjs project

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to add a component in an angular 1 project.My angular folder has templates and js folders.What i had done,is added a template in templates in template folder and a ts in js folder.

Added angular 2 node modules also.Is this enough or anything else i need to add?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Answer (score 1):

ng1 and ng2 differ not only in their dependencies. They require a a different project setup (e.g. the typescript compiler for ng2 needs to be configured and much more)

There is - though - a way to run components from both frameworks side by side: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html

Follow the upgrade-guide if you want to mix components from both worlds or upgrade step by step to ng2.